# JSON Serailizing with VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am trying to serialise some JSON from nested objects into a string.  However I am having issues with the arrays within the objects

```
Class RequestTaxes
    Public Property usrname As String
    Public Property pswrd As String
    Public Property isAudit As Boolean
    Public Property currn As String
    Public Property lines() As TaxLines
End Class


Class TaxLines
    Public Property debCredIndr As Integer
    Public Property goodSrvCd As String
    Public Property grossAmt As Double
    Public Property lnItmId As String
    Public Property qnty As Double
    Public Property trnTp As Integer
    Public Property accntDt As DateTime
    Public Property custVendName As String
    Public Property custVendCd As String
    Public Property orgCd As String
End Class
```

However when I try to pass the serialised string to the API It is refused because the square brackets around the "lines" list are missing.

Does anyone know who to put these in when using Newtonsoft?

```
 Dim Settings As New JsonSerializerSettings
 Settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
 Dim InputString As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Settings)
```

"message" contains a populated object of type RequestTaxes

Comment: What is the exact error message?  I dont think it really has to do with brackets

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Cannot Json deserialize Youtube data with VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45388173/3744182), but we need to see the JSON and the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message, traceback, exception type and inner exception to be sure.

Comment: Looking at that question, it's closely relatied from what we can see, but arguably not a dupe since this is serialising vs deserialising. Nice find though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually needed to do

```
Public Property lines As List(of TaxLines)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your property declarations a bit off.

`Public Property lines() As TaxLines`

is equivalent to

`Public Property lines As TaxLines`

meaning that your TaxLines is only a single instance, not an array.

You need to add parantheses at the end of the line like so:

`Public Property lines() As TaxLines()`