# Deserialize GeoJSON coordinates array using Json.net

Tags: .net, json.net, geojson

I have a GeoJSON geometry that look like this:

```
{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[-121.35753,38.49392]
}
```

I am having trouble creating a class that can represent this. I keep getting "Unable to cast object of type". I assume that its the coordinates array I am having trouble with here.

I have tried both of these class definitions:

```
Public Class GeoJSONPoint
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property coordinates() As Double
End Class

Public Class GeoJSONPoint
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property coordinates as List(Of Double)
End Class
```

After I figure out points, I also need to figure out MultiPolygons which is an array of arrays of arrays that look like this:

```
{
    "type":"MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates":[[[[-118.718979785211,34.2749418860063],[-118.71897943847,34.2746561231818],[-118.719144944,34.2746560927904],[-118.719145294476,34.2749418391076],[-118.718979785211,34.2749418860063]]]]
}
```

Comment: Do you know in advance if the JSON will contain a point or a multipolygon, or is the JSON polymorphic?  Also, you've tagged this as [tag:.net] not [tag:vb.net].  Is a [tag:c#] answer acceptable?

Comment: I have a technique for handling the different entity types as there will be a mix. I just need to figure out the class for each one. Either vb.net or c# will work for me, thanks.

Comment: I think `Public Property coordinates() As Double` should be `Public Property coordinates As Double()` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45388173/3744182) to [Cannot Json deserialize Youtube data with VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45387913/3744182).  But I believe `Public Property coordinates as List(Of Double)` should work; did it?

Comment: I tried `Public Property coordinates As Double()`, no joy. I looked into this as I am old school (emphasis on old) and always put parens on the variable. Turns out in VB.net it does not matter (though there is some debate on this). And sorry no `List(Of Double)` did not work either. That was my first choice as I prefer lists to arrays and Json.net serializes lists into JS arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was not with my class but with how I was deserializing the JSON.

This did not work even though the full error message made it look like the proper type was being implied:

```
Point = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Site.geoJSON)
```

You have to explicitly tell it the type:

```
Point = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of GeoJSONPoint)(Site.geoJSON)
```

A little more testing revealed that I can use a single class definition for the coordinates of Point as well as Polygon and MultiPolygon with their different levels of nested arrays:

```
Public Class geoJSONGeometry
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property coordinates As Object
End Class
```