# How do I loop/iterate through this deserialized object using Newtonsoft Json.net?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have the following JSON object:-

```
    Public Class oPartner
        Public Property PartnerID() As String
        Public Property PartnerTitle() As String
        Public Property PartnerStrapline() As String
        Public Property PartnerData() As String
    End Class
```

And the following partners.json JSON file:-

```
[
  {
    "PartnerID": "1",
    "PartnerTitle": "TITLE1",
    "PartnerStrapline": "STRAP1",
    "PartnerData": "SOME INFO IN HERE",
    "PartnerImage": ""
  },
  {
    "PartnerID": "2",
    "PartnerTitle": "TITLE2",
    "PartnerStrapline": "STRAP2",
    "PartnerData": "SOME MORE INFO IN HERE",
    "PartnerImage": ""
  },
  {
    "PartnerID": "3",
    "PartnerTitle": "TITLE3",
    "PartnerStrapline": "STRAP3",
    "PartnerData": "MORE INFO",
    "PartnerImage": ""
  }
]
```

So I can read the JSON and deserialize using:-

```
Dim data As oPartner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of oPartner)(File.ReadAllText("c:\partners.json"))
```

But I can't work out how I would loop through the json in vb (or C#)?

Comment: You need to deserialize as a list not a single object, i.e.  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of oPartner))`

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON represents an array of objects, but you are trying to deserialize it into a single instance.  You need to deserialize into an array (or List) of `oPartner` instead.  Try it like this:

```
Dim data As List(Of oPartner) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of oPartner))(File.ReadAllText("c:\partners.json"))
```

Then you can loop through the list like this:

```
For Each partner As oPartner In data
    Console.WriteLine(partner.PartnerID)
    Console.WriteLine(partner.PartnerTitle)
    Console.WriteLine(partner.PartnerStrapline)
    Console.WriteLine(partner.PartnerData)
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N8Im6q

Comment: I believe `Public Property PartnerID() As String` defines a single string property, not a string array.  `Public Property PartnerID() As String()` would define an array.  The first `()` is actually redundant.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45388173.

Comment: @dbc Ah yes, you are right, of course.  I've revised.  Thanks!